# ¿Como agregar un array a otro array en firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

estoy empezando con firebase y react, necesito agregar cuantas direcciones quiera el usuario en una aplicacion, pense que se podria hacer mediante un update pero la hacerlo si afecta la base pero obvio me borra los datos que se tienen.
mi estructura de base a la que quiero llegar es la siguiente:

```
{
  uid: 'dnjfnofqnvoveovn3irur80u08ur0',
  nombre: 'Ivan',
  apellidos: 'Julio Monrot',
  Telefono: '5555555555',
  direcciones: {
    casa: {
    calle: 'calle 1',
    numero: '453',
    pais: 'Mexico'
  },
  local:{
    calle: 'Av. Industrial',
    numero: '2123',
    pais: 'Mexico'
  },
```

}

los datos como nombre, apellidos y telefono ya esta ingresados, las direcciones se ingresaran posteriormente, pero no logro hacerlo, tengo un formulario del cual envio los datos al hook para ingresarlos a firebase, mi codigo para ingresarlos es el siguiente:
`import { db } from './firebaseConfig';
import { doc, updateDoc} from "firebase/firestore";

const actualizarDireccion = async ({uid,data}) => {

```
const layOutData = {
    calle: data.calle,
    numeroExterior: data.numeroExterior,
    colonia: data.colonia,
    municipioDelegacion: data.municipioDelegacion,
    entidadFederativa: data.entidadFederativa,
    codigoPostal: data.codigoPostal,
    numeroTelefonico: data.numeroTelefonico,
    referencia: data.referencia
}

const casa = {casa: layOutData}
const local = {local: layOutData}

await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", uid), 
    data.nombreDireccion === 'casa' ? casa : local
);
```

}

export default actualizarDireccion;`

de igual forma no se si es buna practica como estoy colocando los datos, por favor ayuda

Answer (score 0):

En el código anterior se estába utilizando `updateDoc` para actualizar el documento en Firestore. Esta función reemplaza completamente el contenido del campo `direcciones` con el nuevo objeto `direccion` que se proporciona.

Para solucionar este problema y agregar múltiples direcciones sin borrar las anteriores, puedes modificar el código para obtener primero el documento existente, combinarlo con la nueva dirección y luego actualizar el documento completo con las direcciones actualizadas.

Prueba esta versión modificada del código que debería agregar correctamente nuevas direcciones sin eliminar las anteriores:

```js
import { db } from './firebaseConfig';
import { doc, getDoc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const actualizarDireccion = async ({ uid, data }) => {
  const layOutData = {
    calle: data.calle,
    numeroExterior: data.numeroExterior,
    colonia: data.colonia,
    municipioDelegacion: data.municipioDelegacion,
    entidadFederativa: data.entidadFederativa,
    codigoPostal: data.codigoPostal,
    numeroTelefonico: data.numeroTelefonico,
    referencia: data.referencia
  };

  const direccionSnapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', uid));
  const userData = direccionSnapshot.data();

  const direcciones = userData && userData.direcciones ? userData.direcciones : {};

  if (data.nombreDireccion === 'casa') {
    direcciones.casa = layOutData;
  } else {
    direcciones.local = layOutData;
  }

  await setDoc(doc(db, 'users', uid), {
    ...userData,
    direcciones
  });
};

export default actualizarDireccion;
```

Utilizamos `getDoc` para obtener el documento existente antes de realizar modificaciones. Luego, combinamos el objeto `direcciones` existente (si existe) con la nueva dirección. Finalmente, utilizamos `setDoc` para guardar el documento completo actualizado en Firestore, en lugar de utilizar updateDoc que reemplaza el contenido completo del campo. Esto asegura que las direcciones anteriores se conserven mientras se agregan nuevas direcciones.

Comment: Si me funciono para ingresarlo, pero cuendo agrego otra direccion, me borra la primera, ejemplo, primero lleno los datos con la direccion llamada casa, sin problema se agrega, pero cuando agreg otra direccion llamada local, se agrega esta nueva pero me borra la de casa, supongo que es por que se esta haciendo un update de direcciones.

Comment: Quizás es porque estás utilizando `updateDoc` para actualizar el documento en Firestore. Esta función reemplaza completamente el contenido del campo `direcciones` con el nuevo objeto `direccion` que se proporciona.

Usando `getDoc` se obtiene el documento existente antes de realizar modificaciones. Lo combinas con el objeto direcciones existente (si existe) con la nueva dirección. Con `setDoc` guardas, en lugar de utilizar `updateDoc` que reemplaza el contenido completo del campo. Esto asegura que las direcciones anteriores se conserven mientras se agregan nuevas direcciones.